# Why mongoose model .create() is missing out properties on the record

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to save an object to a collection, but I'm missing properties when I try to save a document with it. See the schema below

```
const ordersScheme = new Schema(
  {
    userId: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true
    },

    Delivery: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
      trim: true
    },
    Address: {
      address_line_1: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        trim: true
      },
      coordinates: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        trim: true
      }
    },
    line_items: []
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

now when I try to push a product, the saved document is missing properties for the object inside line_items array.

So this is the exact same payload:

```
{
    "userId": "649ba737f4c1f0c385d7c5a2",
    "Delivery": false,
    "Address": {
        "address_line_1": "No Address",
        "coordinates": "No Coords"
    },
    "line_items": [
        {
            "_id": 1688390766597,
            "product": {
                "Type_field": "Product",
                "Product_Category": "ACCESSORY UNPAINTED",
                "Product_Image": "https://somewebsites.dddd.net/static/1678120139378_1_main__2___2_.jpg",
                "Category": {
                    "display_value": "Fence Accessory Unpainted",
                    "ID": "5"
                },
                "Product_Name": "READY CONCRETE - 15KG",
                "Item_Size_Attribute": "15KG",
                "ProductNumber": "100015",
                "Parent_Product": "",
                "Variation_Type": "",
                "Colours_Available": [],
                "Price_GST": "11.22",
                "Item_Width": "0",
                "Price": "9.29",
                "Item_Material_Attribute": "Concrete",
                "Item_Height": "0",
                "ID": "601",
                "Length_Type": "Standard"
            },
            "colours": [],
            "relations": [],
            "image": "https://somewebsites.dddd.net/static/1678120139378_1_main__2___2_.jpg",
            "ID": 601,
            "quantity": 1,
            "customSize": 0,
            "selectedColour": null,
            "IDD": "6493e09761dc1406da49adea"
        }
    ],
    "total_cost": "9.29"
}
```

I don't understand what's the issue, when I try to specify every property in the Schema, I don't get even a quarter of the information. With line_items: [], I'm getting most of them with missing a few.

This is what I'm getting saved in the DB with the Schema and Payload above. See how quantity, customSize and other properties are missing from line_items objects.

```
{
    "type": "success",
    "message": "Order created successfully",
    "data": {
        "message": {
            "userId": "649ba737f4c1f0c385d7c5a2",
            "Delivery": true,
            "Address": {
                "address_line_1": "No Address",
                "coordinates": "No Coords"
            },
            "line_items": [
                [
                    {
                        "_id": "6493e09761dc1406da49adea",
                        "product": {
                            "Type_field": "Product",
                            "Product_Category": "ACCESSORY UNPAINTED",
                            "Product_Image": "https://d213123.dddd.net/static/1678170139378_1_main__2___2_.jpg",
                            "Category": {
                                "display_value": "Fence Accessory Unpainted",
                                "ID": "5"
                            },
                            "Product_Name": "READY CONCRETE - 15KG",
                            "Item_Size_Attribute": "15KG",
                            "ProductNumber": "100015",
                            "Parent_Product": "",
                            "Variation_Type": "",
                            "Colours_Available": [],
                            "Price_GST": "11.22",
                            "Item_Width": "0",
                            "Price": "9.29",
                            "Item_Material_Attribute": "Concrete",
                            "Item_Height": "0",
                            "ID": "601",
                            "Length_Type": "Standard"
                        },
                        "colours": [],
                        "relations": [],
                        "image": "https://d213123.dddd.net/static/1678170139378_1_main__2___2_.jpg",
                        "ID": 601
                    }
                ]
            ],
            "_id": "64a2ce30b4faf7b52b564bbb",
            "createdAt": "2023-07-03T13:33:36.839Z",
            "updatedAt": "2023-07-03T13:33:36.839Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend creating a schema for your subdocuments. You are trusting Mongoose to correctly identify all the fields of your nested array of subdocuments. When you omit a schema for the array, it defaults to the "Mixed" schema type.

Try defining a schema for the array of subdocuments: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#arrays